# Singleton of a proper class becomes empty?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I'm working on Morse–Kelley set theory, I guess.

Let $\mathfrak Mx$ mean that the class $x$ is a set, abbreviating $\exists C, x \in C$.

By the axiom of class comprehension, the following singleton class $\{x\}$ can be constructed:

$$ \{x\} = \{y: y = x\}. $$

However, the axiom of class comprehension requires the elements to be sets. So the following holds:

$$ \forall y, [y \in \{x\} \leftrightarrow (y = x \land \mathfrak My)]. $$

Since $$(y = x \land \mathfrak My) \to \mathfrak Mx,$$ $\neg \mathfrak Mx$ would imply $\forall y, y \notin \{x\}$, and therefore $\{x\} = \varnothing$. This is a disappointing result, in that it fails to satisfy the definition of a singleton, *i.e.* $|\{x\}| = 1$.

Should singletons, power sets, cardinality, *etc.* apply only to sets?

Comment: Note that $x \in \{x\}$

Comment: @G.Chiusole So the singleton of a proper class should not be constructed?

Comment: Yes, exactly---

Comment: It's not even that a singleton of a proper class *should not* be constructed: you've shown that it *cannot* be constructed in MK, in the sense of getting a set with a cardinality of 1. I'm not sure why you would see this as disappointing; the alternative would be disastrous in MK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We like to forget that definitions are sort of equations. When you say $y=\{x\}$, you are writing an equation that states that two objects are equal to each other. Or rather, you assert that given $x$, you *want* to have an object $y$ satisfying the above equation.

Does $1=2$? No. Does the equation $x^2<0$ holds for any $x\in\Bbb R$? Also no.

Not every equation has a solution. Just because you can write something doesn't mean that it exists. The same is true in English, or any other language, quite obviously.

If $x$ is a *proper* class in KM or NBG, then $\{x\}$ simply does not exist. It makes sense as much as $\sqrt{-1}$ in $\Bbb R$, or $\sqrt2$ in $\Bbb Q$, or $\frac12$ in $\Bbb Z$, or $-1$ in $\Bbb N$. Those are all objects we can write, but do not exist *in that system*. So $\{x\}$ is not empty or anything, it simply does not exist.

So what can we do? We can extend KM to allow collections of classes, i.e. $2$-classes or hyperclasses, as they are known. And then we can extend to $3$-classes, and $n$-classes for all $n$, etc. But you just get a type theory at the end.